# Flutter bloc snackbar and yielding state twice

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

How to achieve showing snackbar without losing bloc state?

Suppose i have this widget class

```
              Scaffold(
                body: LoadingOverlay(
                child: Container(
                    child: BlocConsumer<PostingBloc, PostingState>(
                      bloc: newBloc,
                      listener: (context, state) async {
                        if (state is PostingSuccess) {
                          //Show Snackbar
                        }
                builder : (context, state){return Container(child:Text(state.text))}
                }
```

then the bloc state is like this

```
class PostingState extends Equatable{
String text;
}

class PostingSuccess extends JobPostingState{
}
```

and the bloc mapEventToState is like this

```
PostingStateget initialState => PostingState();

Stream<PostingState> mapEventToState(
    PostingEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SuccessPost) {
      yield PostingSuccess();
      yield state;
    }
```

Is it the correct way to implement snackbar on the bloc state management do i really need to yield twice to make the text still shown without the need to adding new variable like boolean showSuccess etc on my PostingState class.
Or is it the wrong way since there will be a time when the text is gone which is when the Posting Success emitted? I am quite confused on how to do this on bloc, any suggestion is really appreciated. thankyou

Comment: Felix Angelov has a recipe for snackbar usage with bloc in docs. Check it https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesfluttershowsnackbar

Comment: @SimonSot yes, i already saw it but the difference is in that recipe when the state change to succeess the blocbuilder show difference ui, while what i want is the ui still showing the initial ui

Comment: @JoIzal then it is even simpler, aint it? You inside `BlocBuilder` call `if(state is PostingSuccess) { showSnackbar }` and when state change to PostingSuccess snack is shown. And delete `yield state` from bloc logic, thats some weird stuff.

Comment: @SimonSot thankyou, but i still dont get it if i yield PostingSuccess then the state will be PostingSuccess right? then how can i get the text inside this widget Container(child:Text(state.text)) when i yield it? or should i pass all the state of the previous state to this new PostingSuccess state? (this assuming that default value of text is empty/null then i add value to PostingState state, then if i yield PostingSuccess wont the text value become gone?)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your String inside your event and your state. After that:

```
if (event is SuccessPost) {
      yield PostingSuccess(text: event.text);
}
```

Comment: i see so whenever i need to call snackbar i need to copy all the existing property inside postingstate to postingsuccess?

Comment: if you need it yes